Ubuntu 24.10 will not suspend on wayland with nvidia gtx 1070 graphic card
I have problems suspending my pc on fresh install of ubuntu 24.10. I enabled the suspend.service and the resume.service.  Also created modprobe.d nvidia.conf with this line: options nvidia NVreg_PreserveVideoMemoryAllocations=1 NVreg_TemporaryFilePath=/>. But it didn't help.

Which Nvidia driver are you using? Working well with Wayland is a pretty current development.

I'm using  version 560.35.03.

I have the same problem. Even deleting nvidia-driver-560 and installing nvidia-driver-535 (this version works on Ubuntu 24.04) still does not work. (GTX 1050)
I had a similar problem on 24.04 when it was just released, but then I could not wake up and just had errors on the screen. The problem was fixed with an update. I think it will be similar in this case.
At the moment I think the solution is a change in the Nouveau driver.
You can change it in Additional Drivers
or
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau

After that you need to restart your system:
sudo reboot

